# Proving that for $f\geq0$ on $X$, $\int_X f d\mu = 0$ iff $f = 0$ a.e.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Okay, so the question is the following:
Suppose $f \geq 0$ is a measurable function on the measure space $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$. Prove that

\begin{align} \int_X f d\mu = 0 \text{ if and only if } f = 0 \text{ almost everywhere.} \end{align}

I've sort of finished the proof, but my version is not very elegant or simple. I was wondering if there is a simple proof of the statement. It's meant to be using only the basics of Lebesgue integration, i.e., simple functions, etc. Thanks!

Comment: For the nontrivial direction, first prove: if $\{ x:f(x)=0\}$ does not have measure $0$, then for some positive integer $n$, the set $\{ x:f(x)>1/n\}$ has positive measure.

Comment: see the book "elements of integration "  of Bartle . there have a elegant and a simple proof ^^

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The (almost) only fact needed is

**Fact:**  If $0\le f\le g$, then $\int f\le \int g$.

One direction of your assertion is easy:

Suppose $f$ is nonnegative and that the set
$E=\{ x : f(x)>0\}$ has measure zero. Then we have, using the Fact: $$0\le\int f\le\int \infty\cdot\chi_E=\infty\cdot\mu(E)=0.$$

For the other direction, prove the contrapositive:

Assume the set $E=\{ x : f(x)>0\}$ has positive measure. We proceed as suggested by my comment above.  For $n$ a positive integer, define the set $E_n=\{x: f(x)>1/n \}$. Note that

$\ \ \ 1)$ $E=\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^\infty E_n$

and

$\ \ \ 2)$  $E_1\subset E_2\subset E_3\subset\cdots\,$.

From $1)$ and $2)$ (and a result referenced by the "almost" of the first paragraph) it follows that $\mu(E)=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} E_n$. Consequently, it follows from our assumption that $\mu(E)>0$  that there is some $n$ with $\mu(E_n)>0$.

So, with this in hand, using the Fact again, we have:
$$
\int f \ge \int_{E_n} f\ge \textstyle{1\over n}\cdot\mu(E_n)>0.
$$

---

Whether or not this is "elegant" is debatable ...

Comment: I think in 2) that should be $\subset$ not $\supset$. Then you used the Monotone Convergence Theorem for Sets.

Comment: @julien First comment: Blech, thanks. Second comment: This is a proof by contraposition, not contradiction.

Comment: You're right, of course. Where has my logic gone...?

Comment: @Stromael Yes, that's right on both counts. The answer has been corrected now.